# Pojos in Maven 2, filtering classes

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm deploying a web application to a service which requires me to package some of the classes to a Jar file.

So in example having the following source tree:

```
com.enterprise
   |------ package1
   |------ package2
   |------ package3
```

How can I create a jar including only classes from package1 and package3 but not package2?

Comment: You may want to consider making two (or more) sub modules that contain (or depend on) only the items packaged with that artifact.  I find this is cleaner than using excludes and allows you to create a .jar for package1+2 and another for package3 easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the Maven jar plugin with the [`maven.jar.excludes`](http://maven.apache.org/reference/plugins/jar/properties.html) property that contains a list of what paths don't get included into the jar file. To my knowledge this property is automatically used when invoking `mvn jar:jar`.

Or you can directly configure the plugin to include/exclude paths:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>client</classifier>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/service/*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Might be easier to specify just the files you want to include rather than the ones you want to exclude http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#includes

Comment: @matt that always depends on how complex the real structure is. I'm normally in favor of blacklisting small amounts than listing everything _but_ the ones to leave out.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the jar plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com/yourcompany/package2/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You probably want to do this inside a profile